# CSS sliding div (Transition / Transform not working in Firefox 25.0.1)

Tags: css, firefox, transform, css-transitions, transition

I am attempting to create a sliding div that comes in from the right when you hover over the div. It works in Chrome, but not in firefox... what am I missing? It works correctly in Chrome and Safari...

http://jsfiddle.net/mwilday/MVw57/1/

css:

```
    .gettingstarted {
    -ms-transform: translate(200px, 0px);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(200px, 0px);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform: translate(200px, 0px);
    transform: translate(200px, 0px);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
.gettingstarted:hover {
    -webkit-transition: .8s;
    -moz-transition: .8s;
    transition: .8s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="frontpagetile">
    <div class="gettingstarted">
        <p style="text-align: left;">Getting Started</p>
        <ul>
            <li style="text-align: left;"><a href="http://www.google.com">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li style="text-align: left;"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span style="line-height:         1.231;">Link</span></a>
            </li>
            <li style="text-align: left;"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span style="line-height: 1.231;">Link</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just tested it.. it appears to work in FF.

Comment: nightly 28, working fine

Comment: working for me in FF.

Comment: Wrong fiddle... :( http://jsfiddle.net/mwilday/MVw57/1/

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle uses the :hover selector on the .gettingstarted element, which is not visible. Change the selector `.gettingstarted:hover {}` to `#frontpagetile:hover .gettingstarted {}` so that the hover change takes place when the parent element is hovered.